# Puppet - Dependencies between two nodes

Tags: puppet

I am installing two different application on two different nodes. But These two applications have a dependency with each other. Service for application 1 should be started only if application 2 on node 2 is deployed.

Can anybody help on how can I resolve this in my puppet manifests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe puppet is not the right tool for distributed deployments.

You could write a **custom fact** to detect whether node 2 is deployed and then, use this fact as value for the `ensure=>`, or use **exec** resources instead of **service** resources.

Anyway it will be a bit handicraft. Consider using **fabric** or any other tool for distributed deployment orchestation, and use puppet to keep centralized configuration integrity.

Comment: Hi Raul,

Thanks for your inputs. Can Mcollective be useful in this some way?

Comment: Thats the idea. puppet for defining resources and a orchestation tool for achieve ordered deployments